# arcpy two conditions in SQL statement

Tags: arcpy, sql

SQL statements in Python continue to plague me. I'm trying to get the following expression written in a stand alone script:

[image]

This is what I've got so far but I don't think it's even close to the right syntax. I continue to get a syntax error at each iteration of this statement I try. Is there a guide to placing operands, field names, values, double and single quotes?

```
QF5 = "Week"
QF6 = "Wk"
WC4 = '" QF5" + ' <> "'" + QF6 + "'" AND '" QF6" + ' <> "''''"
```

Comment: @ziggy has a good answer below but here is a tip. One thing I do sometimes when I have complex SQL queries and I need a hint as to how they might look in python; I will set up the query in model builder or run the select tool then use the option to export to a python snippet. While the output is usually not the best code, it can give you clues as to how the query can be set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should always avoid using the + sign for concatenation. it gets really clunky as you can see. You should be using the .format method, it is cleaner

```
QF5 = "Week"
QF6 = "Wk"
WC4 = " '{}' <> '{}' AND '{}' <> '' ".format(QF5,QF6,QF6)
```

output = `'Week' <> 'Wk' AND 'Wk' <> ''`

if the above doesnt work try this

```
QF5 = "Week"
QF6 = "Wk"
WC4 = """ '{}' <> '{}' AND '{}' <> '' """.format(QF5,QF6,QF6)
```

output  =`'Week' <> 'Wk' AND 'Wk' <> ''`